# MySql product\tag query optimisation 

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have an sql query i am struggling to optimise. It basically is used to pull back products for a shopping cart. The products each have tags attached using a many to many table product_tag and also i pull back a store name from a separate store table. Im using group_concat to get a list of tags for the display (this is why i have the strange groupby orderby clauses at the bottom) and i need to order by dateadded, showing the latest scheduled product first. Here is the query....

```
SELECT `products`.*, `stores`.`name`, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.taglabel ORDER BY tags.id ASC SEPARATOR " ") taglist
FROM (`products`)
JOIN `product_tag` ON `products`.`id`=`product_tag`.`productid`
JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`id`=`product_tag`.`tagid`
JOIN `stores` ON `products`.`cid`=`stores`.`siteid`
WHERE `dateadded` < '2010-05-28 07:55:41'
GROUP BY `products`.`id` ASC
ORDER BY `products`.`dateadded` DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Unfortunately even with a small set of data (3 tags and about 12 products) the query is taking 00.0034 seconds to run. Eventually i want to have about 2000 products and 50 tagsin this system (im guessing this will be very slooooow). Here is the ExplainSql...

```
id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra
1|SIMPLE|tags|ALL|PRIMARY|NULL|NULL|NULL|4|Using temporary; Using filesort
1|SIMPLE|product_tag|ref|tagid,productid|tagid|4|cs_final.tags.id|2|
1|SIMPLE|products|eq_ref|PRIMARY,cid|PRIMARY|4|cs_final.product_tag.productid|1|Using where
1|SIMPLE|stores|ALL|siteid|NULL|NULL|NULL|7|Using where; Using join buffer
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Guessing doesn't scale well. If you want to know how the system will perform with 2000 products and 50 tags, generate that much sample data. Generate, say, 10K sample transactions, and run your query against the samples using MySQL's EXPLAIN 'query'. Repeat with 100K and with 1M transactions.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you do not need to worry.

- Having 2000 products would NOT take 100 times longer than 20 products. That's what indexes are for (and databases, really...).
- 2000 records is still a very small table for MySQL.

I think you can leave the query as is and you'll soon find out that it runs fine.

Only once the result set gets **really** big (bigger than the system's memory - e.g. several GBs), the sorting may take a while since the DB will use the disk, this is when you can start worrying. In this case it is sometimes useful to create a temporary table for the unsorted results, add an index to it, and them select from it with `ORDER BY`.